# Refused to execute script because its mime type is ('text/html')

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to create a simple website which allows users to add products to my squarespace website using an API. However, I keep getting the following error:

> localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from
> 'http://localhost:3000/main.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is
> not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Here is the index.html code (don't mind the mess):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/main.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/styles.css"> -->
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="">Input a product</h1>

    <label for="product-supplier">Product supplier: </label>
    <input id="product-supplier" type="text" required="true">
    <br>
    <br>

    <label for="product-title">Product title: </label>
    <input id="product-title" type="text" required="true">
    <br>
    <br>

    <label for="product-description">Product description: </label>
    <input id="product-description" type="text" required>
    <br>
    <br>

    <label for="product-list-price">Product list price: </label>
    <input id="product-list-price" type="text" required="true">
    <br>
    <br>

    <label for="product-sale-price">Product sale price: </label>
    <input id="product-sale-price" type="text" required>
    <br>
    <br>

    <label for="product-tags">Product tags: </label>
    <input id="product-tags" type="text" placeholder="supplier, equipment type, additional info" required>
    <br>
    <br>

    <label for="product-image">Product images: </label>
    <input id="product-image" type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg" required>
    <br>
    <br>

    <label for="product-weight">Product weight: </label>
    <input id="product-weight" type="text" placeholder="Enter weight in pounds" required>
    <br>
    <br>

    <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my server.mjs file:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const __filename = new URL(import.meta.url).pathname;
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Serve static files from the 'public' directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// Define a route handler for the root path
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: '.' });
});

app.post('/proxy', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('API request received:', req.body);

  const fetch = await import('node-fetch').then(module => module.default);

  const apiUrl = 'https://api.squarespace.com/1.1/commerce/products';
  try {
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer taken out for security',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('API response:', data);
    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in API request:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

and main.js file:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const productSupplier = $("#product-supplier");
  const productTitle = $("#product-title");
  const productDescription = $("#product-description");
  const productListPrice = $("#product-list-price");
  const salePrice = $("#product-sale-price");
  const productTags = $("#product-tags");
  const productImage = $("#product-image");
  const productWeight = $("#product-weight");
  const submitButton = $("#submit-button");

  const productImageArray = [];

  productImage.addEventListener("change", () => {
    const file = productImage.files;
    productImageArray.push(file[0]);
  });

  const post = (url, data, options) => {
    return fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: options.headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
      }
      return response.json();
    });
  };

  submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert("test");
    const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/proxy";
    const apiKeyOrOAuthToken = "";
    const userAgent = "testing";
    const filePath = productImageArray[0];

    // Create the headers
    const headers = {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKeyOrOAuthToken}`,
      'User-Agent': userAgent,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    // Create the request data
    const requestData = {
      type: "PHYSICAL",
      storePageId: "",
      name: productTitle.value,
      description: `<p>${productDescription.value}</p>`,
      tags: [productTags.value],
      isVisible: true,
      variants: [{
        sku: "SQ0557856",
        pricing: {
          basePrice: {
            currency: "CAD",
            value: salePrice.value,
          },
        },
      }],
    };

    post(apiUrl, requestData, { headers })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  });
});
```

I've tried an exact file path, the localhost file path you see now, I've tried having it in a different folder, I've tried multiple different ways of calling it in my server file and nothing seems to work.

Note, I am still in school and this is my first time working with servers in JavaScript so I could have royally messed something up.

Comment: Tip: Line breaks should not be used for spacing. Use margin, padding, flexbox gap, etc.

Comment: @isherwood I usually would use CSS for spacing, however, it is also giving me the same error for my CSS file, so I just took it out temporarily. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: In the code you shared I cannot see your 'main.js'
I think the problem could be related to your declaration

    <script src="http://localhost:3000/main.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

if index.html and main.js are in the same root, you should try the follow

    <script src=".../main.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

as localhost:3000 is the address of the server you created in node, therefore, it's not related to your client code (main.js)

Comment: Where is that *main.js* file located? Maybe you meant `/public/main.js`?

Comment: @marcocarminati I have added the main.js file, and that solution unfortunately did not work

Comment: @Bergi it was in public, but I have since moved it out, however, both did not work

Comment: @JoshuaCrocker First try to directly visit the URL of the script itself (or check the response in the browser devtools). Does your server serve the script file, or does it serve the default html page (or an html error page)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the directory from which your static assets will be served by express. I presume you have a `public` folder given you have tried linking a css file to there.
Change this:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
```

to this:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

Change this:

```html
<script src="http://localhost:3000/main.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

to this:

```html
<script src="/main.js"></script>
```

As an aside it is common convention to have a `public/js/` folder and a `public/css/` folder and keep their respective `.js` and `.css` files in there. Clearly, you would then reference them in your ejs file links as `/css/styles.css` and `/js/main.js`.

Comment: This unfortunately  did not solve my issue, I still get the same error, but thanks for the tips on the common convention, I'll definitely keep that in mind going forward.

Comment: Did you move `main.js` back into the public folder because you need to? @JoshuaCrocker

Comment: I did move it back in due to the code that you provided above, yes

Comment: @JoshuaCrocker there's not much else that will resolve your issue. By setting `express.static()` to use the `/public` directory that sets the root of static files to the `public` folder. When you then link your JavaScript file and set the src to `/main.js` it essentially just means `/public/main.js`. So as long as put your `main.js` file in the `public` folder then a http request can be made to get the file. The only thing I can advise is to check for spelling mistakes.